# Jquery selector problem

Tags: jquery, regex, css-selectors

I have two  in a table with ids row_26 and notificationrow_26.

I want to highlight row_26. So I use either

```
var deviceUID = 26;
$("#row_" + deviceUID).effect("highlight", {}, 3000);       

OR

$("tr[id^='row_"+deviceUID+"']").effect("highlight", {}, 3000);
```

but when I do this. It also highlights the notificationrow_26 . Also the highlight does not work properly on notificationrow_26. It does not change its color back to original.

Am I missing something?

Comment: I think you need to show more code as your first selector ought to work to highlight that single row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of those selectors work for me to select the single element `row_26`, is that not what you're trying to do? If it is, there may be a problem elsewhere in your code that you haven't included.

`[id^=row_26]` would also match ids like `row_260`, however, which is probably not what you want.

If you wanted to match `(anything)row_26` to catch both the `row` and the `notificationrow` you need an end-of-attribute selector instead of start-of-attribute: `[id$=row_26]`.

[Aside: however if performance is an issue, it is faster to just use two separate selectors, `#row_26` and `#notificationrow_26`, which allows jQuery to use getElementById instead of having to search each element's id. Or you can even call it yourself:

```
$(document.getElementById('row_'+deviceUID)).effect(...);
$(document.getElementById('notificationrow_'+deviceUID)).effect(...);
```

This looks less ‘jQuery-like’, but it's faster and you don't have to worry about ‘special’ characters in the attribute value that don't fit in a selector.]